# how to use php class with html form

Tags: php, html, curl

ok so i created the html form which i wish to connect with the following php class but im clueless on how to get it done because i have never worked on php class before.

here is my form

```
<form action="sms.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uid" value=""/>
<input type="password" name="pwd" value=""/>
<input type="number" name="mobile" value=""/>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="msg"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
```

this is the php class which i need to be able to connect with the above html form

```
<?php
class WAY2SMSClient
{
    var $curl;
    var $timeout = 30;
    var $jsToken;
    var $way2smsHost;
    var $refurl;

    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->curl = curl_init();
        $uid = urlencode($username);
        $pwd = urlencode($password);
        // Go where the server takes you :P
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://way2sms.com");
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $a = curl_exec($this->curl);
        if (preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
            $this->way2smsHost = trim($r[1]);
        // Setup for login
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->way2smsHost . "Login1.action");
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=" . $uid . "&password=" . $pwd . "&button=Login");
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie_way2sms");
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->way2smsHost);
        $text = curl_exec($this->curl);
        // Check if any error occured
        if (curl_errno($this->curl))
            return "access error : " . curl_error($this->curl);
        // Check for proper login
        $pos = stripos(curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), "ebrdg.action");
        if ($pos === "FALSE" || $pos == 0 || $pos == "")
            return "invalid login";
        // Set the home page from where we can send message
        $this->refurl = curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $newurl = str_replace("ebrdg.action?id=", "main.action?section=s&Token=", $this->refurl);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
        // Extract the token from the URL
        $this->jstoken = substr($newurl, 50, -41);
        //Go to the homepage
        $text = curl_exec($this->curl);
        return true;
    }

    function send($phone, $msg)
    {
        $result = array();
        // Check the message
        if (trim($msg) == "" || strlen($msg) == 0)
            return "invalid message";
        // Take only the first 140 characters of the message
        $msg = substr($msg, 0, 140);
        // Store the numbers from the string to an array
        $pharr = explode(",", $phone);
        // Send SMS to each number
        foreach ($pharr as $p) {
            // Check the mobile number
            if (strlen($p) != 10 || !is_numeric($p) || strpos($p, ".") != false) {
                $result[] = array('phone' => $p, 'msg' => $msg, 'result' => "invalid number");
                continue;
            }
            // Setup to send SMS
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->way2smsHost . 'smstoss.action');
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ssaction=ss&Token=" . $this->jstoken . "&mobile=" . $p . "&message=" . $msg . "&button=Login");
            $contents = curl_exec($this->curl);
            //Check Message Status
            $pos = strpos($contents, 'Message has been submitted successfully');
            $res = ($pos !== false) ? true : false;
            $result[] = array('phone' => $p, 'msg' => $msg, 'result' => $res);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * logout of current session.
     */
    function logout()
    {
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->way2smsHost . "LogOut");
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->refurl);
        $text = curl_exec($this->curl);
        curl_close($this->curl);
    }
}

function sendWay2SMS($uid, $pwd, $phone, $msg)
{
    $client = new WAY2SMSClient();
    $client->login($uid, $pwd);
    $result = $client->send($phone, $msg);
    $client->logout();
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sms.php**

```
<?php
//include WAY2SMSClient file
include_once 'WAY2SMSClient.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$phone = $_POST['mobile'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$result = sendWay2SMS($uid, $pwd, $phone, $msg);
?>
```

Comment: Argument to `include_once` needs to be a quoted string.

Comment: appreciate it @B.Desai but guess the above code does not work as not sms is being sent

Answer (score 0):

You have a file named WAY2SMSCLIENT.php and you are posting your form data to sms.php.
So from your sms.php you will have to create an object of the WAY2SMSCLIENT class and then on that object you may call the methods passing them the required data as parameters.
Am sorry as I can't post the code right now as am using phone and am traveling now. But if is still hard for you let me know i will try my level best to help you.

Comment: Hi @simplysaif will appreciate it. whenever you can do share your code too.

Comment: The anser @B.desai posted must work fine. You need to debug your code. If sms are not being sent you should post the error that you are getting. I would have posted the same code.
try this  var_dump( $client->login($uid, $pwd)); and check what value is being returned by your login function'

Comment: yes it is working but not can i get response if $result has error then message not send if no error then message sent

Comment: You are returning true if login is successful from your login method else you are returning error message. In stead of returning true return 'success' from login method and then inside sendWay2SMS  check like this  $login = $client->login($uid, $pwd); if($login == 'success'){ //send message} else{//show error message}

Comment: will give this a shot and get back. appreciate it